# How does jetty server with ssh modules mix webflux functional endpoint module?

Tags: struts2, jetty, spring-webflux

I have a jetty server running some ssh (spring-struts2-hibernate) modules. It's typically config by a web.xml file. Now I want all new module to use spring-webflux techique with functional endpoints. All ssh modules must keep running. How to mix the new webflux module to this jetty server?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "ssh module" for Jetty. Please explain what you mean in more detail.

Comment: It's just a struts2 project running on a jetty server with a traditional way (use web.xml).